# Facebook login via IOS app redirects to blank page

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I previously had my IOS app integrated with the Facebook Graph API using the IOS SDK.  I recently recreated the app on Facebook and now when it tries to authorize using:

`[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];`

My app gets redirected to a blank Facebook page with a cancel button at the top and then I get a callback to the `fbDidNotLogin()` method in my IOS app.

What's wrong?

I tracked it down to line 315 of Facebook.m:

`if (!accessToken) {`

It then eventually calls `fbDialogNotLogin:NO`.  The errorCode and errorReason don't appear to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your access token is expired or you removed the app from your facebook. You can log what error is returning to you from facebook to find out. In any case if you get to fbDidNotLogin implementation you need to remove access token details from NSUserDefaults (if you store it there) and reauthorize.

hope this helps

Comment: My token was indeed invalid and the only way I could tell was from `-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`.     `[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];` was calling `fbDidLogin` even though the token was invalid.